# Definitive List Of SharePoint Enterprise Features For Licensing Purposes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, licensing, cal

Is there a definitive list of SharePoint 2010 Features that cause liability for Enterprise CAL's?  (i.e. I want to know all the Enterprise feature names and all the standard feature names so that I can find out at each site collection, web, web application level if it is turned on).

We have the Enterprise Features turned on at the Farm level.  But not all our end-users use Enterprise features.

Really I am looking for a list of features with the following columns of information:

```
FEATURE NAME    FEATURE ID    FEATURE TYPE (STANDARD/ENTERPRISE)    SCOPE
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of standard end enterprise features for sharepoint 2010:
http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2013/10/sharepoint-enterprise-feature-activation-unintended-consequences/

And I think that question very similar to [Removing all Enterprise SharePoint Features from a web application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65352/removing-all-enterprise-sharepoint-features-from-a-web-application)

Comment: Thanks.  The link you have posted is a list for 2013. Is the list for 2010 the same?

Comment: I am sorry for list of sharepoint 2013 features. The Lists are not the same.Sharepoint 2013 includes new features.

Comment: I have updated my question.  The information missing from every list I can find is the FEATURE TYPE (STANDARD/ENTERPRISE) column information.

Answer (score 2):

To be in compliance it's more than just ensuring you have deactivated certain features.  Technically once you have enabled an enterprise service - it's available to everyone and needs to be licensed as such.

The best way to go forward with this is to call your Microsoft licensing rep and let him know your intentions. Microsoft can and will work with you (if you have an active SA agreement that is) in customizing a licensing agreement that works for you.

Comment: We are in compliance but I still want to know the list of which Features are enterprise so that I can turn off the Enterprise features that are not in use.  I have been unable to find a definitive list with information about whether each feature is standard or enterprise so hence the question I have asked.

Comment: I don't know that anyone has put together an actual feature comparison or even an inventory.  I would imagine one exists - as you actually need this info when setting up multi-tenancy deployment, but I have not seen one published for 2013 (MS has one for 2010).  I would wager you may be able to get it from them - I'm sure they provide it to hosters. Not feature by feature but have a look here - http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/

Comment: Thank you.  None of the links posted so far answer the question of which features require an enterprise license for SharePoint 2010 though.  The last link is closer but it is really just a list of features and whether they are available or not in the various editions of SharePoint 2013.